# Как подружить room и dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dagger2, room

Только начал изучать Dagger 2 и столкнулся с ошибкой.
Есть класс App. В нем я собираю компонент и передаю Context в модуль DataBaseModule.

```html
public class App extends Application {

    private AppComponent mApplicationComponent;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mApplicationComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().dataBaseModule(new DataBaseModule(this)).build();
    }


    public AppComponent getComponent() {
        return mApplicationComponent;
    }

}
```

В модуле DataBaseModule я хотел бы собрать бд и предоставлять dao. Но это невозможно так как контекст в таком случае будет нулевым.

```html
@Module
public class DataBaseModule {

    private AppDataBase dataBase;
    private Context context;

    @Inject
    DataBaseModule() {
        dataBase = Room.databaseBuilder(context
                , AppDataBase.class, "database")
                .build();
    }

    public DataBaseModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public AppDataBase getDataBase() {
        return dataBase;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public CategoryDao getCategoryDao(AppDataBase db) {

        return db.categoryDao();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public ExpensesDao getExpensesDao(AppDataBase db) {
        return db.spendingDao();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public FinPlanDao getFinPlanDao(AppDataBase db) {
        return db.finPlanDao();
    }

}
```

Какие есть пути решения данной проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Module
public class DataBaseModule {

    private Context context;

    public DataBaseModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public AppDataBase getDataBase() {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDataBase.class, "database").build();
    }

    // остальные методы
}
```

Ничего тут не нужно кэшировать, `@Singleton` всё сделает за вас. Да и кэшировали вы неправильно, зачем-то сделали второй конструктор с `@Inject` в котором и создавали БД, а не в том, в котором `context`

Получаете в активити ваш кэшированный в `App` компонент и инжектите базу данных

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я пробовал такой вариант инициализации,но получал следующую ошибку : DataBaseModule cannot be provided without an Inject constructor or from an Provides- or Produces-annotated method. void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

Comment: Компонент 

`@Component(dependencies = {}, modules = {DataBaseModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}`

Comment: И передача в MainActivity  `((App) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);`

Comment: @Rkz потому что вы где-то требуете заинжектить DataBaseModule, чего делать не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо. Как я могу в таком случае (без Inject) получить модуль databasemodule в MainActivity,ведь согласно документации, поле получаемого модуля должно помечаться аннотацией  Inject.